# Cell in snake game grid always going to the top of the screen

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard

In my computer science class, I am assigned to code a mod for a basic snake game program. I decided to add a feature where when the user presses the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> bar, it will shoot out a portal depending on what mode the user is in (similar to the game Portal). To start with the basics, I decided to start with the shoot method, and wanted it to be animated.

I managed to get the blue/enter portal working, but when I tried to implement the same methods to the orange/exit portal, it just automatically goes to the top of the screen.

I have tried to change the variables from local to global, using extra functions instead of just doing it in one, banging my head against the wall over and over again but nothing is working. ***What am I doing wrong?***

## Code

### Dictionary for portals

```py
ENTERP = 0
EXITP = 1

portalPos = [  # The first dict is the enter portal, and the second dict is the exit portal
        {"x": random.randint(0, 31), "y": random.randint(0, 23), "dir": ""},
        {"x": random.randint(0, 31), "y": random.randint(0, 23), "dir": ""}
]
```

### Key Checks

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():  #
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a) and direction != RIGHT:
                    direction = LEFT
                elif (event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d) and direction != LEFT:
                    direction = RIGHT
                elif (event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w) and direction != DOWN:
                    direction = UP
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s) and direction != UP:
                    direction = DOWN
                elif event.key == K_p:
                    print(exitPortAniCount)
                elif event.key == K_SPACE:

                    if portalGunMode == "ent":
                        portalPos[ENTERP]["dir"] = direction
                        portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] = wormCoords[HEAD]['x']
                        portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] = wormCoords[HEAD]['y']
                        enterPortAniCount = PRANGE

                    if portalGunMode == "ext":
                        portalPos[EXITP]["dir"] = direction
                        portalPos[EXITP]['x'] = wormCoords[HEAD]['x']
                        portalPos[EXITP]['y'] = wormCoords[HEAD]['y']
                        exitPortAniCount = PRANGE

                elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
```

### Portal bound checks

```py
def checkPortalBounds():

    if portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] >= 31:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] = 31
    elif portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] <= 0:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] = 0
    elif portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] >= 23:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] = 23
    elif portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] <= 0:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] = 0

    if portalPos[EXITP]['x'] >= 31:
        portalPos[EXITP]['x'] = 31
    elif portalPos[EXITP]['x'] <= 0:
        portalPos[EXITP]['x'] = 0
    elif portalPos[EXITP]['y'] >= 23:
        portalPos[EXITP]['y'] = 23
    elif portalPos[EXITP]['y'] >= 0:
        portalPos[EXITP]['y'] = 0
```

### Update portal animations

```py
def updatePortalAnims():
    global enterPortAniCount, exitPortAniCount

    for i in range(PRANGE):
        if not enterPortAniCount <= 0 and not portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] == 31 and not \
                portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] == 0 and not portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] == 23 and not \
                portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] == 0:
            if portalPos[ENTERP]['dir'] == RIGHT:
                portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] += SHOOTSPEED
                enterPortAniCount -= 1

                checkPortalBounds()

            elif portalPos[ENTERP]['dir'] == LEFT:
                portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] -= SHOOTSPEED
                enterPortAniCount -= 1

                checkPortalBounds()

            elif portalPos[ENTERP]['dir'] == UP:
                portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] -= SHOOTSPEED
                enterPortAniCount -= 1

                checkPortalBounds()

            elif portalPos[ENTERP]['dir'] == DOWN:
                portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] += SHOOTSPEED
                enterPortAniCount -= 1

                checkPortalBounds()

        if not exitPortAniCount <= 0 and not portalPos[EXITP]['x'] == 31 and not \
                portalPos[EXITP]['x'] == 0 and not portalPos[EXITP]['y'] == 23 and not \
                portalPos[EXITP]['y'] == 0:
            if portalPos[EXITP]['dir'] == RIGHT:
                portalPos[EXITP]['x'] += 1
                exitPortAniCount -= 1

                checkPortalBounds()

            elif portalPos[EXITP]['dir'] == LEFT:
                portalPos[EXITP]['x'] -= 1
                exitPortAniCount -= 1

                checkPortalBounds()

            elif portalPos[EXITP]['dir'] == UP:
                portalPos[EXITP]['y'] -= 1
                exitPortAniCount -= 1

                checkPortalBounds()

            elif portalPos[EXITP]['dir'] == DOWN:
                portalPos[EXITP]['y'] += 1
                exitPortAniCount -= 1

                checkPortalBounds()

        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the following segment of code:

```
if portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] >= 31:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] = 31
    elif portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] <= 0:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] = 0
    elif portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] >= 23:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] = 23
    elif portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] <= 0:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] = 0

    if portalPos[EXITP]['x'] >= 31:
        portalPos[EXITP]['x'] = 31
    elif portalPos[EXITP]['x'] <= 0:
        portalPos[EXITP]['x'] = 0
    elif portalPos[EXITP]['y'] >= 23:
        portalPos[EXITP]['y'] = 23
    elif portalPos[EXITP]['y'] >= 0:
        portalPos[EXITP]['y'] = 0
```

The final elif has the wrong symbol, you have >= when it should be <=.
Currently as it reads it is "If y is greater than 0, make it 0", therefore it will always be 0.

Additionally whilst this won't be effecting this bug, pesonally I'd change the second elif in each block to an if, as it is possible for two values to be out of bounds and if so this code will correct the x issue but not the y, therefore the corrected code is:

```
if portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] >= 31:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] = 31
    elif portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] <= 0:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['x'] = 0
    if portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] >= 23:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] = 23
    elif portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] <= 0:
        portalPos[ENTERP]['y'] = 0

    if portalPos[EXITP]['x'] >= 31:
        portalPos[EXITP]['x'] = 31
    elif portalPos[EXITP]['x'] <= 0:
        portalPos[EXITP]['x'] = 0
    if portalPos[EXITP]['y'] >= 23:
        portalPos[EXITP]['y'] = 23
    elif portalPos[EXITP]['y'] <= 0:
        portalPos[EXITP]['y'] = 0
```